# Video.js spinner not dissapearing in IE

Tags: video.js

[This video](http://goo.gl/s8qQO) is set to autoplay and loop. The start is ok. Wheel spinning video loading. But after the first playback the spinner comes up again. Any solution for this?

Maybe this is related issue:

> The test video on videojs.com when opened through Internet Explorer.
>   Click play, then skip to near the end of the video. It's not set to
>   loop, but anyway after the playback it returns to the start in Paused
>   mode, and you can actually see the spinner behind the play button.
>   However it's not animated, in my case it's spinning.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be isolated to IE, as I'm getting the same spinner after the first play in Chrome (v23).

Comment: I see this issue in Chrome and Firefox too. I don't have looping set, the spinner just comes up again after the video finishes playing.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this: `data-setup='{"children": {"loadingSpinner": false}}'` to your video tag, it will remove the spinner.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a fairly common [issue](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/1465-loading-spinner-is-shown-after-video-was-played) with VideoJS. I noticed you already set `display: none;` on the `.vjs-loading-spinner` element and that's not working, so I was able to get rid of it by using jQuery to [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) the element from the dom.

```
$('.vjs-loading-spinner').remove();
```

That should take care of the problem, though I realize this is probably not ideal.